# The deadly fish!

Tags: riddle, language

> For some, I am just fish
>
> For others however, I'm deadly
>
> In Japan, I can be both, or neither.
>
> When two letters are changed, 
>  I turn from killing into healing one

What am I?

Comment: My instinct tells me this puzzle employs the use of different languages and translations of the word fish and deadly, but I could be wrong

Comment: @GordonAllocman You are right; I figured it might be fair to add the language tag. However, it is not impossible to solve the puzzle without knowing the other language involved.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I'll just give it a shot. Is the answer:

> Pois(s)on?

*For some, I am just fish*

> The French word for fish is poisson

*For others however, I'm deadly*

> In English, poison is deadly

*In Japan, I can be both, or neither*

> In Japan a poisonous fish (Fugu) is a delicacy, which might explain part of this line. Not sure though.

*When two letters are changed,

I turn from killing into healing one*

> When you change poison into potion, it becomes something healing

Comment: This is the correct answer! Last part of the third sequence: *poison*, or something that sounds similiar, is not fish or poison in the Japanese language.

Comment: In French, poison (single s) means the same as in English, by the way. It only means fish when adding a letter, not because of switching languages, which weakens the point a bit.Although I can feel a similar question coming up about des(s)ert...